# React server middleware api (Deploying)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js (Vue.js) where is a way to get your Express api in a exiting nuxt.js project.
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/

Is there a way in React to get the same functionalitie ?? And yes i now you can do in react a proxy but that is not the same. I want to develop a backend in a diffenent place and then just add it in the react application just like i do it in nuxt.js.

Comment: I did not yet found a way to to serverMiddelware in react did somebody else find it ??